# Creating Hexagon Grid over streets using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, hexagonal-grid

I have a street layer of a city. I want to create a `hexagon grid`within the streets. I `buffered` the streets with 20m, I `unionized` them. The next step would be creating `hexagons` within the streets. However, my result is rather strange. I get a straight line

[image: straight line].

I'd expect a `hexagon grid` with the layout of a streetnetwork.

```
WITH baseStreet AS (
    SELECT 
        ST_Union(
            ST_Buffer(geom , 20, 'endcap=round join=round')
        ) AS geom
    FROM all_streets
), hexagons AS (
    SELECT 
        ST_HexagonGrid(5, baseStreet.geom) AS hex
    FROM baseStreet
) SELECT (hex).* FROM hexagons LIMIT 100;
```

Or is that not possible, and I have to make an `envelope` of the streetnetwork, create a `hexagon grid` within this `envelop` and then do a `clip` or `intersect` to identify the `hexagons` that are of relevance?

Comment: Hexagonal grids and clipping such is a topic that comes up from from time to time, there are already a few questions that are fairly close. Although I'm not an expert with PostGIS the part that sticks out to me is the *LIMIT 100*, it's possible that all your hexagons are being created but you're only seeing the first 100 generated. I would also expect that the grid is generated over the entire extent of baseStreet.geom even if there are no geometries that intersect all the hexagons, you'll probably need to do a geometry selection if you want just the hexagons that intersect your streets.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I ended up doing this

```
WITH baseStreet AS (
    SELECT 
        ST_Union(
            ST_Buffer(geom , 20, 'endcap=round join=round')
        ) AS geom
    FROM all_streets
), bbox AS (
    SELECT ST_Envelope(geom) AS geom FROM baseStreet 
), hexagons AS (
    SELECT ST_HexagonGrid(5, bbox) AS hex FROM baseStreet
), hexOnStreets AS (
    SELECT (hex).geom FROM hexagons 
    JOIN all_streets
        ON ST_Intersects((hex).geom, baseStreet.geom)
) SELECT * FROM hexOnStreets;
```

Create a `bbox` of the street network, fill it with a `hexagon grid` and then perform a `spatial Join` on the hexagons and streets.